# add and remove div attribute with checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox, random

i need to add id to div.

my code not work.

```
    <div class="quote-box-col14" for="seo">
<label for="seo" class="quote-service-seo">SEO</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="seo" id="seo" value="Y" class="checkbox-seo" />
</div>
```

js code

```
$('#quote-box-col14').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $( "#quote-box-col14" ).attr( "id", "check" );
    } else {
       $( "#quote-box-col14" ).removeAttr("id");
    }
});
```

js fiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/3syqfnzk/

Comment: There is no element with ID `quote-box-col14`. Use `$(".quote-box-col14")` to select via CSS class instead. Additionally, `.quote-box-col14` is a `div` which doesn't have a change event

Comment: what do you exactly want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong id. Use on change event of `#seo` instead of `#quote-box-col14`.

And `$( ".quote-box-col14" )` instead of `$( "#quote-box-col14" )`.

Use like:

```
$('#seo').change(function(){

        if($(this).is(":checked")) {

            $( ".quote-box-col14" ).attr( "id", "check" );
        } else {
           $( ".quote-box-col14" ).removeAttr("id");
        }
    });
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3syqfnzk/9/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no `id="quote-box-col14"`. `quote-box-col14` is a class.
Also you are not listening on the `checkbox`. Simply listen on `#seo`.

```
    $('#seo').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('.quote-box-col14').attr("id", "check");
        } else {
           $('.quote-box-col14').removeAttr("id");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="quote-box-col14" for="seo">
  <label for="seo" class="quote-service-seo">SEO</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="seo" id="seo" value="Y" class="checkbox-seo" />
</div>
```

Jquery Code For this should be

```
$('#seo').change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
  $( ".quote-box-col14" ).attr( "id", "check" );
} 
else 
{
  $( ".quote-box-col14" ).removeAttr("id");
}
    });
```

This will work fine for you because onChange should use for input type for example 
`<input type="checkbox" name="seo" id="seo" value="Y" class="checkbox-seo" />` not div 
Also class can be access by `.` not `#`

```
 Note: # use for id and .use for class
```

Working Example is [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3syqfnzk/11/)
You can view this by inspect Element